# Highcharts Renderer: Should I use attr() or css()?

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

When using the Highcharts [Renderer](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Renderer) to draw shapes, the drawn [Elements](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Element) have a css() function and an attr() function. It seems like we can style an element using either, although the syntax is slightly different.

Example:

```
// using attr
renderer.rect(100, 100, 100, 100, 5)
    .attr({
        stroke: 'red',
        'stroke-width': 2,
        fill: 'green',
        'fill-opacity': 0.5
    })
    .add();

// using css
renderer.rect(250, 100, 100, 100, 5)
    .css({
        stroke: 'red',
        strokewidth: 2,
        fill: 'green',
        fillopacity: 0.5
    })
    .add();
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Asheq/qLz83xnk/

Is there a reason to choose one over the other?

Comment: By default, Highcharts apply graphic options by attr() function.